# React JSX returning TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My JSX returns undefined even though the data is fetched immediately from the useEffect hook. I've tried nesting it within logical operators, console logging everything, I'm at a complete loss. I believe I'm traversing the Json correctly, so I don't understand why my data keeps returning undefined even though the data is clearly logged in the console.

[Console of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY2AV.png)

```
const WeatherContainer = () => {
    const [searchTerm, setsearchTerm] = useState('new york city')
    const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState({});
    const [forecastedWeather, setForecastedWeather] = useState({});
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false); 
    
    const handleInput = (e) => {
        setsearchTerm(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSearch = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        fetch(`/weather/${searchTerm}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                setCurrentWeather(result)
            })
        setLoading(false)
    };
    console.log(currentWeather)
    useEffect(() => {
       handleSearch()
    }, [])


    return (
        <>
            <div className='search-bar'>
                    <input className='text_input' type='text' name='searchTerm' onChange={handleInput} placeholder='Enter city' />
                    <button className='search-button' onClick={handleSearch} type='submit' value='submit' name='button'>
                        <Icon icon={searchIcon} flip="horizontal" />
                    </button>
            </div>
            
            <div className='weather_container'>
                
                {currentWeather ?
                <>
                    <h1>{ currentWeather.main.temp}</h1>
                </>
                : <Loader />}
            </div>
        </>
    )

};
```

After setting currentWeather Hook to an empty value, this is the console log

[Updated console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CL1G.png)

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Empty objects are truthy, so you’ll need to add `currentWeather && currentWeather.main && currentWeather.main.temp`. Or you could use  lodashs `isEmpty` as an alternative

Comment: @James TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined

Comment: @MattCarlotta Mate that was it thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you initialized the object in your useState Hook, the Object automatically starts as an empty object which will return truthy with you logical check. You can check if there is values in your object by checking the keys length in your state. An empty object has a length of 0 and populated will have a length of 1.

Try this code in your return statement

```
<div className='weather_container'>
                {Object.keys(currentWeather).length > 0
                    ? <h1>{currentWeather.main.temp}</h1>
                    : <Loader />
                }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
{currentWeather ?
<>
    <h1>{ currentWeather.main.temp}</h1>
</>
: <Loader />}
```

You're checking that `currentWeather` exists, but assuming that its `main` property exists.  In this case, it doesn't.  Because when the component first loads it creates a default `currentWeather` object with no properties:

```
const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState({});
```

So the rendering will throw an error before the operation to fetch the data completes.  In this case you can probably just default to no object at all for `currentWeather`:

```
const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState();
```

That way in the initial render `currentWeather` will be "falsey" and will render the `<Loader />` component instead.

---

Alternatively, you could also explicitly check both when rendering:

```
{currentWeather && currentWeather.main ?
<>
    <h1>{ currentWeather.main.temp}</h1>
</>
: <Loader />}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I set the initial state like you said and I refresh I get my Loader and then the same TypeError, but new undefined in the console. I will update with the new console log

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
currentWeather?.main?.temp
```

The problem with your current code is you are just checking if `currentWeather` exists or not. However, even if it exists, you need to check if the `main` object exists or not.

The proposed solution above, leverages optional chaining (`?.`). So essentially we are checking if `currentWeather` exists and if it does then we go on to check if `main` exists and if it does, then we render the value of `temp`

More on Optional Chaining: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining